# How do you use Ajax with Django to submit a form without redirecting/refreshing, while also calling the views.py function?

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I would like to create a system for bookmarking posts, where there would be a page of posts to scroll down, and if you like one in particular, you can click on a button to save it to your bookmarks. I've searched the entire day for a solution that allows me to save the post to the User's Bookmarks, while also not refreshing/redirecting, but I have only managed to find methods that solve one problem at a time, not both. I'm not interested in changing the template view itself, but rather just saving the data into the database.

My Template Code:

```
<form class='bookmark-form' method='POST' action="{% url 'add_bookmark' %}" 
      data-url='{{ request.build_absolute_uri|safe }}'> {% csrf_token %}
             <input type="text" value="{{post.pk}}" name="post-pk" hidden>
             <button type='submit'><img src="/img/bookmark.svg" alt=""></button>
</form>
```

My Ajax Code:

```
$('.bookmark-form').submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault() 
      var postData = {csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),}
      var $formData = $(this).serialize()
      var $thisURL = $('.bookmark-form').attr('data-url') || window.location.href 
      $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: $thisURL,
          data: postData,
          success: function (data) {console.log(data)},
          error: function(data) {console.log("Something went wrong!");}
      })
      return false;
  })
```

My Views.py Function to save the bookmark:

```
def add_bookmark(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        pk = request.POST.get('post-pk')
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        user = request.user 
        user.bookmarks.add(post)
        user.save()
        print(user.bookmarks.all())
        return JsonResponse({'result': 'ok'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'result': 'nok'})
```

The current result is that the page doesn't reload/redirect, but it never calls the add_bookmark function either.

You can probably tell I'm fairly new to Ajax as well. Could someone shed some light as to how I could possible achieve both of my objectives at once?

Edit: Rendered HTML
[image: Rendered HTML]

Console Log (Not entirely sure why it's logging the entire HTML file for data):
[image: Console Log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong URL for submitting. You should use the `action` attribute, not the `data-url`.

```
$('.bookmark-form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault() 
    var postData = {csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),}
    var $formData = $(this).serialize()
    //var $thisURL = $('.bookmark-form').attr('data-url') || window.location.href 
    var form_action =  $('.bookmark-form').attr('action')
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: form_action,
        data: postData,
        success: function (data) {console.log(data)},
        error: function(data) {console.log("Something went wrong!");}
    })
    return false;
})
```

If your HTML is different, you basically have to pull the URL somewhere else. You can even hardcode the view's path in the AJAX function.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: '/add_bookmark', # or whatever your URL IS
    data: postData,
    success: function (data) {console.log(data)},
    error: function(data) {console.log("Something went wrong!");}
})
```

Comment: That also doesn't seem to be working hmm...thank you though.

Comment: What does `console.log(form_action)` and `console.log($thisURL)` output?

Comment: The form_action is undefined, and $thisURL outputs http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: Can you inspect element your form and paste a screenshot of the rendered HTML.

Comment: The html inside the image you uploaded does not contain the form you have above. Can you press the Elements tab in the inspector, and navigate to your form, and take a screenshot of that.

Comment: Oh, the form itself is simply the bookmark (submit) button. I made the input hidden to access the primary key of the post itself later on in the views function to save the data. I could definitely change it to a simple button if that makes it easier.

Comment: haha that's a completely different question given the difference in given, but to cut to the chase, you have to make that URL available somewhere (either in the `form` tag as an `action` attribute, or as a `data-url` in your button,  or a hardcoded URL in your JS). I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you so much!! This seriously helped a ton. One more small question - in my template, i run through each post in posts, and create a new form for each post to bookmark it. If I add the post's primary key to the end of my url (action="{% url 'add_bookmark' post.pk %}" in the form), it only ever gives me the first post's pk. Do you have any insight on that?

Comment: We'll need to see the actual/updated code again of your urls.py, your template, your view, and the rendered HTML. I suggest you post a new question and post the link here, I'd be happy to answer it again.